# Is "<tr><th/><td/></tr>" a legal HTML snippet?

Tags: html

I have a HTML code snippet:

```
<table>
 <tr>
  <th>a header</th>
  <td>some content</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

the rendering is as it would be a table with two columns. Is it a legal HTML code?

Comment: for practice http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_tables

Comment: In case of making a table with horizontal headers, you have to make <th/><td/> combinations, so that's legal! ;)

Comment: But what's the difference between making a combination and just putting two <td/>s with the same content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For which version of HTML? The W3C validator is pretty definitive:

http://validator.w3.org/check

It validates ok as HTML 4.01 transitional.

Comment: Any W3C standard related links?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is valid ! 
Use http://htmlhelp.com/tools/validator/direct.html.en